# Generic media queries for devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm looking for a list of generic CSS media queries to match phone (both portrait and landscape), tablet (both portrait and landscape) and desktop.
I have found many posts with some generic media queries, but they are often different and maybe I don't understand them.

For instance, the following query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { }
```

does it match all phones (portrait and landscape) and tablet portrait? Or what?

I also found other examples, like the following:

```
/* mobile */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) { }
/* tablet */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) { }
```

and

```
/* mobile */
@media screen and (max-width:767px) { }
/* tablet */
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) { }
```

Which of the previous queries are correct to correctly match phone (both portrait and landscape) and tablet (both portrait and landscape)?

Thanks

Comment: First and last codes will work in any devices and desktops that fits with the max-width property, doesn't matter if it's a mobile or not. Second example only works in devices between two resolutions, but not in desktop even if the match with the resolution. I think the better options are always target resolutions, not devices, by this mode you are making a responsive web design. If you target devices instead of resolutions, that's not responsive, but that's mobile version.

Comment: If you're concerned about orientation, you can try playing around with the `orientation` feature. Here's the [w3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#orientation) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use media queries, like Marcos said is to use resolutions. Your first code `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { }` will target all the devices that have maximal screen resolution of 768px. So if your phone have a resolution of 640px it will affect it, if your phone have a bigger resolution of 768px the code you enter in {} will be ignored. Usually this is used to make responsive designs, and you use queries with different resolutions for different devices (you can easily find online the most common queries).

Hope it helps.